# Easiest way to control a remote bitcoind instance?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core

What's the easiest way to control `bitcoind` running on a remote machine?

I'd like to make transfers, manage my wallet, etc, and ideally I'd like to do it using a UI such as `bitcoin-qt`.  Unfortunately I don't see how to get `bitcoin-qt` to connect to a remote `bitcoind`.  Is there a different piece of software that can do this?

I know I can use `bitcoind` itself to send commands to a remote instance, but I'm hoping for UI.

--

The reason I'm interested is that I'm happy to leave `bitcoind` running and stay synchronised on one machine, but this is not the same machine that I want to run the UI on.

Comment: Till today, I thought that bitcoind and bitcoin-qt accept the same parameters and switches. If you can connect to remote bitcoind via bitcoind, maybe you can also do it with bitcoin-qt?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using a Linux-based system, [Xpra](http://xpra.org/) is a great tool for running GUI apps headless and attaching to them on a remote system. Make sure you install a recent version from one of the [Winswitch repositories](http://winswitch.org/downloads/debian-repository.html).

I haven't tried the Winswitch front-end since command line usage is so simple. Just do this on your server:

```
xpra start :7
DISPLAY=:7 bitcoin-qt
```

And this on the client:

```
xpra attach ssh:my.server.ip:7
```

Comment: Whooohooo! I have been looking for this kind of X11 tool for years! Thank you so much! I am probably not going to use it for bitcoin, since I am happy with the CLI client there, but this goes for me. Xpra seems perfectly suitable for this.

Comment: This requires the server to have bitcoin-qt installed, which may be undesirable on a simple Linux box with no GUI libs installed.