# How to connect to a remote Bitcoin Core remotely

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core

If I have 24/7 running `bitcoind` on a headless server, is there a graphical way to connect, maybe only temporarily to the server's Bitcoin Core daemon or its client to see if everything is going smoothly on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [a plausible answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9530/easiest-way-to-control-a-remote-bitcoind-instance) which did not work for me, but almost!

**To start it up, follow this:**

1. Install [`xpra`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpra) both on the server, and on the client. On Debian-like OS it would be:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -y xpra
   ```
2. Temporarily stop the Bitcoin Core daemon on the server:

   ```
   bitcoin-cli stop
   ```
3. Over the first SSH connection, start `xpra` on the server like this:

   ```
   xpra start :7
   ```
4. Over the second SSH connection, start `bitcoin-qt` on the server like this:

   ```
   DISPLAY=:7 bitcoin-qt
   ```
5. Connect `xpra` from the client to the server like this:

   ```
   xpra attach ssh:SERVER-IP:7
   ```

**After you have finished your work, follow this:**

1. Close [Bitcoin-Qt](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_Core) on the client
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in this window and close it:

   > ```
   > xpra attach ssh:SERVER-IP:7
   > ```
3. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in this window and close it:

   > ```
   > DISPLAY=:7 bitcoin-qt
   > ```
4. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in this window and don't close it:

   > ```
   > xpra start :7
   > ```
5. Issue this command in the SSH session to the server:

   ```
   xpra stop :7
   ```
6. And finally start your Bitcoin Core daemon again with or without a wallet:

   ```
   bitcoind -daemon -disablewallet
   ```